# What are the general rules for faculty attendance?

Tags: professorship

Other than attending classes and meetings, faculty differ in their daily attendance. Some faculty may show up only during days they have classes, others are in their offices daily from 8-5, others arrive around noon and stay late. Are their any rules or it is up to each department or faculty?

Comment: At the California community college where I teach, this kind of thing is sometimes the subject of negotiations between the union and management. In particular, management doesn't seem to like it that some faculty are only on campus two days a week.

Comment: Why would you think there were universal rules for faculty attendance when job description, specifics of contract, laws, the nature of educational systems across countries, and the type of institution varies so widely across the world?

Comment: @DanielL I should mention in US, but knowing the rules all over would be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It varies very widely depending on individual faculty, departmental, and institutional culture, norms, and rules.

For example, many faculty at my institution live in a city two hours away and only come to campus twice a week for classes and meetings. Faculty performance at my school is measured by lines on the CV, so one can argue that **not** going to school is a more productive use of time if you have a home office.

Meanwhile, while in Japan, I noted that some faculty had to punch timecards that showed their daily attendance. There, faculty performance seemed to be measured by the appearance if diligence rather than actual productivity.

On the extreme other end, adjunct faculty in the USA may not even have an office (or library privileges) to even have office hours.

Comment: +1 for it varies very widely. However, I don't get how you jump from punching timecards to performance being measured  by the appearance of diligence rather than actual productivity. Even if you have timecards and mandatory 40h/week attendance, you could measure performance by what people can accomplish with those 40h/week.

Answer (score 5):

I think you answered your own question. It's up to the department and school. Office hours are usually mandatory for many schools, but these might only constitute an hour a week, and the door might not always be open. If you're curious about your own school's faculty, I suggest e-mailing the department head or checking the class syllabi.